# Cant connect mysql server to visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql

I've been trying to connect my MySQL server to Visual Studio 2017 on my C# Project. The MySQL Server I'm using off of Helios Hosting. Visual Studio Connects to the MySQL Server, But Always Pops Up W/ Error Messages.

Heres My MySQL Connection String Of The SQL

```
        `MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER= The Remote ACESS HOST IP;DATABASE=jordan1g_LoginsDBs;UID=jordan1g;PASSWORD=*****;");`
```

It Worked Fine When I Used A Local SQL Server, Like SQL Express. But the goal here it to have it run connected to the Remote SQL Server

Honestly, I've tried For hours and hours find fixes and try to fix it myself. I'd really appreciate it if you guys could help me out. I'm about to the point of ripping the hair out of my head, and punching my monitor. Thanks! (BTW, I'm not really famillier w/ the community, if I'm doing anything wrong, pls let me know :-))

Comment: Search for how to set up MySQL to allow remote access. you have to make some changes on the MySQL server to allow remote connections.

Comment: I suggest you to connect to SQL server using visual studio server explorer instead of a connection string, if it doesn't work, then there is definitely a problem in your SQL server configuration or amy be with your login information, please try it and let us know if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what the console gives back.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace DatbaseApplication
{
    public class Database
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;

        public Database()
        {
            try
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.0.0;user id=databaseuser;password=databasepassword;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=databasename;allowuservariables=True");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: It comes back with and error saying: "Authentication to host '64.62.211.134' for user ''jordan1g_falconu" using method "MySQL_native_password"failed with message: Access Denied for user "jordan1g_falconu"@"ip(MYPUBLICIP).**.**.cox.net(using password: YES). jordan1g_falconu is my username for the database, jordan1g is my username for heliohosts.

Comment: It is possible that the database does not allow external connections. See if your database settings are correct. Maybe you can try to add the database to your odbc data sources, if that doesn't work there is probably a problem with the settings.

Comment: You will need the MySql odbc driver to try that. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html